# Is it possible to configure Jenkins to use both Active Directory and its own user database?

Tags: authentication, jenkins, active-directory

Is there a way to configure Jenkins to use a combination of Active Directory authentication along with its own user database? For most cases, we want people to be able to use their AD accounts, but there are some cases (for example, integrations with other systems), where we'd prefer not to have to create an AD account and instead simply use a Jenkins user. Is this possible, with or without a plugin?